# Powershell creating microsoft access database error

Tags: powershell, ms-access

I am running the following code in windows powershell:

```
Function Create-DataBase($Db){


$application = New-Object -ComObject Access.Application
 $application.NewCurrentDataBase($Db,10)
 $application.CloseCurrentDataBase()
 $application.Quit()
} #End Create-DataBase


#$dbname = Read-Host -Prompt 'Input your database  name'

# database file location
$Db = 'C:\new.mdb'
If(Test-Path $Db){
    Write-Host 'DB already exists' -fore green
}else{
    Create-DataBase $Db
}
```

But getting the following error,

> Exception calling "NewCurrentDatabase" with "5" argument(s): "An error
>   occurred while trying to create the database." At
>   E:\Mahmood\test2.ps1:3 char:33
>   +  $application.NewCurrentDataBase <<<< ($Db,10)
>       + CategoryInfo          : NotSpecified: (:) [], MethodInvocationException
>       + FullyQualifiedErrorId : DotNetMethodException
>
> Exception calling "CloseCurrentDatabase" with "0" argument(s): "The expression
>   you entered refers to an object that is closed or doesn't exist." At
>   E:\Mahmood\test2.ps1:4 char:35
>   +  $application.CloseCurrentDataBase <<<< ()
>       + CategoryInfo          : NotSpecified: (:) [], MethodInvocationException
>       + FullyQualifiedErrorId : DotNetMethodException

Anyone have any idea what's wrong.

Comment: Works fine for me.  Do you have write permissions to the root of `C`?

Comment: Access to system drive root C:\ is denied by default. Try e.g. `$Db = "$env:temp\new.mdb"`

Comment: Note that the use of the `Access.Application` object just to create new databases is overkill (that initializes the whole application). Try using `DAO.DBEngine.120` instead (and `CreateDatabase` instead of `NewCurrentDb`). That's less prone to errors, and will likely run much faster.